# Sorting Alphabets + Character + Numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a column name `session` in which sessions are stored like

```
fall-2018
fall-2019
spring-2019
spring-2020
```

I want to sort result in ascending order like this:

```
Fall-2018
Spring-2019
Fall-2019
Spring-2020
```

The query that I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student 
ORDER BY session +0 ASC
```

Suggest Please!

Note: There are Five more columns and i have to select all  and then sort by Session

Comment: Is it `MySQL`? `MSSQL`?

Comment: Doesn’t the order by clause work? It should work fine. Can you post the query what you were trying to run.

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: Your data model should have a `SessionStartDate` column in addition to `Session` (which should be named `SessionName`). Not only will that address your ordering requirement, it follows the normalization principle of atomic data so that you don't need to parse data every time it's queried.

Comment: @trincot u r right it was written by mistake.

Comment: bro its mean season or you can say fall semester or spring semester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order them first by year (the last 4 characters) and then by season as follows:

```
select   session
from     students
order by right(session, 4),
         session desc;
```

`session` (i.e. the season) is ordered descending because in any given year the Spring season comes before the Fall season.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ok, then in MS SQL

```
with student as
(
   select 'fall-2018' as "session" union all
   select 'spring-2018' union all
   select 'fall-2019' union all
   select 'spring-2019' union all
   select 'fall-1980' union all
   select 'spring-2055' union all
   select 'fall-2052'
)
select
   s."session"
from student s
order by right(s."session", 4), s."session"
```

Well, in Oracle this *strings* could be sorted like that

```
with student as
(
   select 'fall-2018' as "session" from dual union all
   select 'spring-2018' from dual union all
   select 'fall-2019' from dual union all
   select 'spring-2019' from dual
)
select
   initcap(s."session")
from student s
order by substr(s."session", -4), s."session"
```

Comment: Yes, it would and really works ( just tested if i missed something). Why not?

Comment: well i am using sql server

Comment: and bro i have to fetch all data including session but i have to sort according to session

Answer (score 0):

You can split the year part and do  **order by** with that

```
SELECT Session
FROM student 
order by PARSENAME(Replace(Session,'-','.'), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to use conditional `ORDER BY`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Students (
   [Session] varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Students ([Session])
VALUES 
   ('fall-2018'),
   ('fall-2019'),
   ('spring-2019'),
   ('spring-2020')

SELECT [Session]
FROM #Students
ORDER BY 
   SUBSTRING([Session], CHARINDEX('-', [Session]) + 1, 4),
   CASE 
      WHEN CHARINDEX('spring-', [Session]) > 0 THEN 1 
      WHEN CHARINDEX('fall-', [Session]) > 0 THEN 2 
      ELSE 3
   END
```

Output:

```
Session
----------------
fall-2018
spring-2019
fall-2019
spring-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about my answer that will satisfied your requirement as you don't specified type of sorting like ascending, descending.

However, I have done as per your expected out put.

This code for your reference.

```
Create table #Temp (Value varchar(100))

insert into #Temp values ('fall-2018')
insert into #Temp values ('fall-2019')
insert into #Temp values ('spring-2019')
insert into #Temp values ('spring-2020')

SELECT Value
FROM #Temp order by Convert(int,PARSENAME(Replace(Value,'-','.'), 1)) , 
SUBSTRING(Value, 1, CHARINDEX('-',Value)-1) desc
```

Comment: bro session are not fixed they will increased

Comment: @RajaNaumanHaroon What do you mean fixed ? If you asking with my example then its just sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you last four digits are always year, then this approach will also help you to get the desired output.

```
;with Cte as (Select 'Fall-2018' as   [Session] union all 
          Select 'Fall-2019' as   [Session] union all 
          Select 'Spring-2019' as [Session] union all 
          Select 'Spring-2020' as [Session] ) 
select *  from cte 
order by right(session,4), case when Session like '%Spring%' then 'a'+ session else session end ;
```

Based on the output I had to add a to the cases where we have spring so that it would order before fall. Right will help to make sure we are sorting for the same year.

Output:

```
Session
Fall-2018
Spring-2019
Fall-2019
Spring-2020
```

If it works with Fall fall spring spring format as well (based on year and then alphabetical order).  You can use this,

```
;with Cte as (Select 'Fall-2018' as   [Session] union all 
          Select 'Fall-2019' as   [Session] union all 
          Select 'Spring-2019' as [Session] union all 
          Select 'Spring-2020' as [Session] ) 
select *  from cte 
order by right(session,4), Session ;
```

Output:

```
Session
Fall-2018
Fall-2019
Spring-2019
Spring-2020
```

Comment: the sessions will b incresed every year

Comment: @RajaNaumanHaroon yes as long as it has year component in there

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query which is based on the `year` and delimited by the character `-`.

Remember when you add column as alias and provide `order by` on that column then it works fine on that column without any error. Here `YearName` is run time taken as column alias.

```
with sSession([Session])
as
(
    select 'fall-2018'
    union all
    select 'fall-2019'
    union all
    select 'spring-2019'
    union all
    select 'spring-2020'
)
select [Session] from(
select [Session],
            SUBSTRING([Session], CASE CHARINDEX('-', [Session])
            WHEN 0
                THEN LEN([Session]) + 1
            ELSE CHARINDEX('-', [Session]) + 1
            END, 1000) AS YearName        
 from sSession
 )a 
 order by YearName
```

The output is as shown below

```
Session
----------
fall-2018
spring-2019
fall-2019
spring-2020
```

You can find the demo here- [**Demo<>Order BY**](https://rextester.com/OJL83172)